# Retrieve child by auto id value in firebase (TableView)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I have a UI table view and when I swipe the cell I delete the cell, but not the value in firebase. I have searched everywhere but cannot find it. How can I delete the array I swiped on from the cell in my firebase. Below is how I set up my firebase database. The array I'm trying to delete is the corresponding one in the cell e.g. it may be "-L4BMZBIcYMp_f2LDMbp" etc.

Also the code I have to delete the cell and where I would find the array corresponding to the cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let fliper = self.flipList[indexPath.row]

        if let itemID = fliper.item{
            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Flip").child("..I need to find out how to get child auto id").removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref) in

                if error != nil {
                    print("Failed! to delete message")
                    return

                }
                //one way of updating the table
                self.flipList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                self.tableViewFlips.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            })
        }`
```

Comment: As you say, you need a reference to that ID somewhere. It _looks_ from your code that `itemID` should be what you're looking for, but it all comes down to how you're modeling your data. We don't know what your data looks like, so we can't tell you where this auto ID should be coming from. But some related model object should reference it.

Comment: If your datasource is a `dictionary` or `NSDictionary` you can easily do this just by getting the index of the dictionary. I wouldn't recommend an `Array`, especially if you're populating it inside a `Firebase` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "key" here is to ensure that when the data is initially loaded from Firebase you keep the node key intact. So for example. say you have a messaging app that has posts. Here's a class that would store the data from Firebase

```
struct PostStruct {
   post_key = ""
   post_text = ""
   posted_by_uid = ""
}
```

and then those structs would be used to populate your dataSource array.

Given the above structure:

When your dataSource is initially populated from Firebase, as you read in each post node, create a post struct, populate it with data from Firebase and store it in a dataSource, typically an array.

When you swipe to delete there are about 100 options for handling the actual delete process but here are a couple:

1) Your tableView is backed by an array. If you swipe to delete row 2 (for example), inspect the object (struct) to be deleted, capture the post_key from the stuct, then delete the node from Firebase (since you know the node key) and then query the array for that object key, delete the row in the array and reload your tableView/update the UI.

2) When you swipe to delete a row, inspect the object and obtain the post_key. Then remove the object from Firebase. That would trigger a .childRemoved event (assuming you've attached the corresponding listener). When your app receives that event, determine which object it is (via key or other means) and remove it from the array and reload the tableView.

3) If you swipe to delete row 2, get the struct from row 2 in your dataSource array, read the key from that struct, remove row 2, remove the object from Firebase and reload the tableView.

There are many, many other way to tackle this; your dataSource array could store the actual snapshot data from firebase or it could store a series of key: value pairs with the key being the node key and the value being the data within that node (as a stuct, class, string etc).

**Edit:**

Some additional info to clarify the above.

Supposed we are using the structure above and firebase has matching nodes like this

```
root
  posts
    post_key_0  //created via childByAutoId
      post_text: "some post text"
      posted_by_uid: "uid_0"
    post_key_1  //created via childByAutoId
      post_text: "another post"
      posted_by_uid: "uid_1"
```

then to read the posts and populate a dataSource array:

```
struct PostStruct {
    post_key = ""
    post_text = ""
    posted_by_uid = ""
}

var dataSourceArray = [PostStruct]()

func button0() {
    let itemsRef = self.ref.child("items")
    itemsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
            let postKey = snap.key
            let postText = dict["post_text"] as! String
            let postedByUid = dict["posted_by_uid"] as! String
            let post = PostStruct(post_key: postKey, post_text: postText, posted_by_uid: ppostedByUid)
            self.dataSourceArray.append(post)
        }
        self.someTableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

from there it's pretty straightforward.

Assuming we are using option 3), when the user swipes to delete row 2 for example you get that post from the array, row 2

```
let post = self.dataSourceArray[2]
let postKey = post.post_key
```

now you know the firebase key so it can then be removed

```
let thisPostRef = fbRef.child("posts").child(postKey)
thisPostRef.remove()
```

and finally remove it from the array and refresh the tableView

```
self.dataSourceArray.remove(at: 2)
self.someTableView.reloadData()
```

The code would be different if you went with one of the other options but the concepts are similar and can be applied to each.

Comment: Let’s say I assign a random number to a variable and then have one in every branch in the array, when I swipe a cell, how do I get the contents of the inside of the array corresponding to the cell. So then I could remove the child called “ITEMID” from firebase and it would look for that value and remove it. Could that work and how would I put that in code?

Comment: @TheLegend27 I am not sure what *assign a random number to a variable* means but I think you may be referring to node keys that are created with childByAutoId (which is a key generated by Firebase and guaranteed to be unique). I outlined in detail one option for accomplishing your task. The concept is to simply keep the Firebase node key with the object in your dataSource so you will always be able to reference it in firebase. Regardless of it's a key you generate (random?) or a key firebase generates.